# Создание соединение в SessionListener, передача соединения в servlet

Tags: java, java-ee

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, по заданию нужно создать и закрыть соединение и DAO в SessionListener, при этом соединение надо передать в сервлет, для использования методов (insert, delete, update)

вот сам сервлет:

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

private static String INSERT = "/profile.jsp";
private static String EDIT = "/edit.jsp";
private static String PROFILE_RECORD = "/listProfile.jsp";

protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8");
    request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    super.service(request, response);
}
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String redirect="";
    String profileId = request.getParameter("id");
    String action = request.getParameter("action");
    try {


        DAOFactory daoFactory = new DAOFactory();  //get factory
        ProfileDAO instance = daoFactory.getProfileDAO(); //get connection


        Profile profile = new Profile();
        if(!((profileId)== null) && action.equalsIgnoreCase("insert")){
            int id = Integer.parseInt(profileId);
                profile.setId(id);
                profile.setUserName(request.getParameter("userName"));
                profile.setNickName(request.getParameter("nickName"));
                profile.setUserMail(request.getParameter("userMail"));
                profile.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
            instance.insertProfile(profile);
                redirect = PROFILE_RECORD;
            request.setAttribute("profile", instance.selectAllProfiles());
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
            int profileDelete = Integer.parseInt(profileId);
            instance.deleteProfileId(profileDelete);
                redirect = PROFILE_RECORD;
            request.setAttribute("profile", instance.selectAllProfiles());
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("editForm")){
                redirect = EDIT;
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("edit")){
            String Id = request.getParameter("id");
            int profileEdit = Integer.parseInt(Id);
                profile.setId(profileEdit);
                profile.setUserName(request.getParameter("userName"));
                profile.setNickName(request.getParameter("nickName"));
                profile.setUserMail(request.getParameter("userMail"));
                profile.setPassword(request.getParameter("password"));
            instance.updateProfile(profile);
                request.setAttribute("profile", profile);
            redirect = PROFILE_RECORD;
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("listProfile")){
            redirect = PROFILE_RECORD;
            request.setAttribute("profile", instance.selectAllProfiles());
        } else {
            redirect = INSERT;
        }
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(redirect);
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e){
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(request, response);
}}
```

Написал класс SessionListener, в котором должен получить соедение (за правильность реализации не уверен, поэтому прошу помощи, как правильно выполнить это задание, проще говоря необходимо передать соединение ("instance" в данном случае в сервлет)

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener{
ProfileDAO instance = null;
ServletContext servletContext = null;
private int sessionCount;

public SessionListener() {
    this.sessionCount = 0;
}
@Override
public void sessionCreated (HttpSessionEvent event) {
    synchronized (this) {
        sessionCount++;
    }
    DAOFactory daoFactory = new DAOFactory();
    try {
        instance = daoFactory.getProfileDAO();
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    servletContext = event.getSession().getServletContext();
    servletContext.setAttribute("instance", instance);
}
@Override
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
    synchronized (this) {
        --sessionCount;
    }
    try {
        instance.close();
    } catch (DAOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}}
```

Comment: А как насчет того чтобы положить instance в саму сессию а потом в сервлете из той же сессии ее и получить
event.getSession().setAttribute("connection", instance);

Comment: Так и реализовал, всё верно.